# Add isCompleted switch and track completed events

Tags: calendarkit

There is no story board to this library so where would I add a switch to add a isCompleted reference so I can store reoccurring events as completed or not.
Any ideas thanks

Comment: Please, provide more context for your question. Very likely you'll have to create your own data structure which conforms to the `EventDescriptor` protocol, similarly to this: https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp/blob/master/Calendar/EKWrapper.swift